# Failing to insert into BigQuery using google-cloud node.js client

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I have a Node-RED installation running with the BigQuery node that all of a sudden stopped working. Have been able to narrow it down to a very small example which I can't get to work anymore:

The code looks like this:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

// Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
const projectId = 'my-project';
const file = './google-cloud-auth.json'

// Creates a client
const bigquery = new BigQuery({
  projectId: projectId,
  keyFilename: file
});

const datainsert = {
    "water_total": 555,
    "power_vp": 3460651,
    "power_ftx": 4401819,
    "time": "2018-01-23T09:50:17.672Z",
    "power_total": 5737457,
    "power_garage_radiator_south": 182521,
    "power_garage_radiator_north": 76388
};
// The name for the new dataset
const dataset = bigquery.dataset('consumption');
const table = dataset.table('consumption_test');
table.insert(datainsert, function(err, response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

When I run this on my Ubuntu machine (NodeJS v4.8.7) it outputs:

```
{}
undefined
```

and nothing gets written to BQ.
However, when I run the exact same code (in fact I have tried to copy the entire folder structure) on my Mac (NodeJS v6.9.4) it outputs:

```
null
{"kind":"bigquery#tableDataInsertAllResponse"}
```

and the record is stored successfully.

Obviously I thought it was related to the Node version so I tried running it in the very Docker container it used to run but with NodeJS v6.9.4 but it still doesn't run successfully on that machine. I'm running with the same authentication file so I don't think it's related to that.

Would anyone happen to know what it is within my environment that causing this to happen?

Answer (score 5):

After several hours of head scratching I finally found the problem to be clock slightly out of sync on the machine (5 minutes). I realized this when I decided to run other commands to see if they worked. When trying to get a list of datasets I got the following (quite helpful) error back:

> [Error: invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token
>   (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp
>   values and use a clock with skew to account for clock differences
>   between systems.]

Problem solved.